# React search functionality for table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a react project in which I'm using table and I need to add a search functionality to it. Right now the table is populated with objects.

```
function createData(Estimate, ServiceProvider, Vehicle, Date, Amount, Status, Action) {
    return {Estimate, ServiceProvider, Vehicle, Date, Amount, Status, Action};
}
const rows = [
    createData('#10001', "Euro Motors", "2010 Toyota Corolla CE FWD", "January 28, 2021", "$395.11", "Approved",),
    createData('#10002', "Auto Motors", "Some car model", "January 28, 2021", "$395.11", "Pending"),
    createData('#10003', "Some other Motors", "Some other car model", "January 28, 2021", "$395.11", "Approved"),
]
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(rows)
```

Right now I have search functionality for just ServiceProvider using this

```
const requestSearch = (searchedVal) => {
    const filteredRows = rows.filter((row) => {
        return row.ServiceProvider.toLowerCase().includes(searchedVal.toLowerCase());
    });
    setTableData(filteredRows);
};
```

but I need it for Estimate, ServiceProvider, Vehicle. How can I extend the functionality to all three so whatever the user searches in the search bar it checks all three columns and filters out rows with repeation.

Comment: Just add the conditions for Estimate, and Vehicle and combine them using `||` operator within the `requestSearch` function.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor does this also take care of repeations?

Comment: Repititions in what sense? Each row, matching on more than one criteria will only appear once.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor your solution is good. Can you please answer the question so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the conditions for `Estimate`, and `Vehicle` and combine them using `||` operator within the `requestSearch` function, like this:

```
return row.ServiceProvider.toLowerCase().includes(searchedVal.toLowerCase()) ||
 row.Estimate.toLowerCase().includes(searchedVal.toLowerCase()) ||
 row.Vehicle.toLowerCase().includes(searchedVal.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generic solution for all the keys without actually mentioning the keys individually.
Try following code snippet:

```
const requestSearch = (searchedVal) => {
    const filteredRows = rows.filter((row) => {
        let found = Object.values(row).map(o => o.toLowerCase()).find(o => o.includes(searchedVal));
        if(found) return true; 
        else return false;
    });
    console.log(filteredRows);
};
```

Note: this will work if all of your search values are string, for number you'll need to add some conditional handling to it.